# You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**codeigniter 2.2.2** No changes were made to the site code on the site, only work was carried out through the site admin panel to add information to the site. I do not understand why this error appeared, since before that everything worked correctly. This may have happened because a new ssl certificate was installed. **Error: You must use the set method to update a record. File name: admin_m.php Line number: 25** This error occurs when you try to edit information on the site through the admin panel.

> ```
> function getInfo()
>     {
>         $this->db->select();
>         $this->db->from('tbl_info');
>         $this->db->where('id', 1);
>         $query = $this->db->get();
>         
>         return $query->result();
>     }
>     function editInfo($data)
>     {  
>     
>         $this->db->where('id', 1);
>         $this->db->update('tbl_info', $data); // the error refers to the given line of code
>         return TRUE;
>     }
> ```

Comment: You need to update the version because at this time Codeigniter 2 is outdated.

Comment: How to do it? Is it possible to solve the problem without updating?

Comment: you can check official document for that